# .Net Client Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClient UploadObjectAsync 503 periodically error, low frequency

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

Code snippet:

```
//create storage 
var _client = StorageClient.Create();
//make api call
await _client.UploadObjectAsync("bucketName", input.Key, "contentType", 
file);
```

Problem description:

Periodically(< 5%) I receive error Google.GoogleApiException with 
    ex.Error.Code == 503.
More interesting, if user will reupload same file(perform same operation over same file, there is great chances that reupload will be without error)

> Error text: Google.GoogleApiRequestException:
>   Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Backend Error [503] Errors [
>   Message[Backend Error] Location[ - ] Reason[backendError]
>   Domain[global] ]

My solution:

I apply retry mechanism that will try to upload again N times.

My question:

What can cause this 503 Google.GoogleApiException ?
What does error mean and where I can find error code description, so I can understand what caused this issue?

4 sep 2018, I see from 0.5% to 10% this error rate.
5 sep 2018, I see 0% this error rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

50x errors are all back end server errors.  Something went wrong on the server and it was not able to process your request.  There is nothing you can do about it except try again.

> 503 SERVICE UNAVAILABLE
>   The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overload or scheduled maintenance, which will likely be alleviated after some delay.